# Dart `void` vs `Function` vs `void Function()`

Tags: function, flutter, dart, types, void

Flutter's `InkWell` widget has an `onTap` argument of type `void Function()`. If I declare and pass a void method, I get a type error `This expression has a type of 'void' so its value can't be used.` If then I use a `Function` instead, I have to also `return null;` explicitly. I would like to only use a void, and leave out the explicit return statement.

Can someone explain the difference between these types?

- `void`
- `Function`
- `void Function()`

(I was unable to find an exact answer to this, although it might sound similar to other questions.)

Comment: Can you show the part of your code which gives the type error?

Comment: I'm sorry, I meant for this to be a general question, but I see that the input argument to the void question was the one giving the type error. I will supply the code once I have the time, or vote to delete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is: `InkWell` Widget's `onTap` takes a callback `void Function` (a function that doesn't return anything) which will be run every time user presses the button.

It's hard to know for sure since you didn't share the code but I would guess that  you're likely running the function instead of passing it without the parenthesis. Because you're invoking or running the function you are not passing it, instead you're passing the returned `void`.

Try passing the function without parenthesis so it doesn't get run.